# Is there a reason why my browser cannot read the property of addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

My addEventListener property to my button makes my if/else statement not work

```
(from other function)   document.getElementsByClassName('btn-purchase')[0].addEventListener('click', purchaseClicked);


function purchaseClicked() {    

if (document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0].hasChildNodes()){
    alert('Thanks!')
    window.open("payment.html","_self");

}   
else {
    alert("There is nothing in your cart!");
    }
```

}

When clicking the button when the cart is empty, the user should be alerted that there is nothing in the cart, however, it just carries on with the true of statement rather than the false statement.

Comment: what errors do you see in the developer tools console

Comment: sorry for changing it! It says it cannot read property addEventListener of undefined.

Comment: that means `document.getElementsByClassName('btn-purchase')[0]` is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no problem with the way you are getting the button element, however make sure the html of it is in the DOM and the class name is well specified on the button tag. If you want to debug it a bit more try to assign the button element to a variable and use "debugger" to see what happen in there.

e.g

```
let button = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-purchase')[0];
debugger;

if (button) {
  button.addEventListener('click', purchaseClicked);
}
```

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('btn-purchase')[0].addEventListener('click', purchaseClicked);


function purchaseClicked() {    
  alert("this works");
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-purchase">Click me</button>
```